# 16 point Sinc Interpolation Kernel

Tags: filters, interpolation

I have a signal that is sampled at Fs and wish to apply a "16-point Sinc interpolation kernel". However, I am not sure what the 16-point refers to. Does it refer to having a kernel that is represented by 16 samples? How can I generate such a kernel in python?

EDIT:
I was hoping to resample the cosine signal using the code that follows. Could you point out what I might be wrong or any misconceptions I might be having?

```
# my signal is y
t = np.arange(0,5,0.1) # dt = 0.1 => sampling rate 10hz
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t) #2hz => fs >= 2 BW

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y,'.-')
```

[image]

```
# Sinc Filter

x = np.arange(-3*0.1, 4*0.1, 0.01)
h = np.sinc(x/0.1)
```

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,h,'.-')

[image]

```
out = np.convolve(y,h)
newt = np.linspace(0,t[-1],len(out))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(newt, out)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Hari and welcome to DSP SE. I believe you should either provide your approach, i.e. what you have tried, what doesn't work for you, etc. Otherwise, divide the question down to "smaller" ones. From the question I understand that you are unfamiliar with signal interpolation. Maybe you should start with that. You can find some information to start with at this (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Delay_Line_Signal_Interpolation.html) site from Stanford University.

Comment: "16-point sinc interpolation" probably means a windowed-sinc kernel that is 16 original samples long, looking at 8 samples on the left and 8 samples on the right.